# How to set the standard "Allowed" and "Secondary" addable content types for all Members in Plone? (folder_constraintypes_form)

Tags: plone

Within Plone 4.2, how can I constrain the addable content types for all members?

All my members (400 at the momemt and growing), should have a default set of content types to be addable within there "Home" folder (/Members/mymember). That is, if mymember goes to his Home folder, there should only be a few content types like "Document", "Image" and "File" as default addadle types. All other content types like Events, Collection etc. should only be under the "More" menu item of the "Add" menu.

I thought I could just set "Use parent folder setting" for each myplone.org/Members/mymember/folder_constraintypes_form ("Restrictions" item of "Add" menu). And then from the parent myplone.org/Members/folder_constraintypes_form I would set up the default content types as I like. That is all members' Home folders could inherit from the setting in Members. However, as a plone site administrator I cannot set the standard "Allowed" and "Secondary" ("More..." menu) for the /Members/ folder. I do allow have the possibility to select either

- Allow the standard types to be added
- Specify types manually

That is, there is no "Specify types manually" for /Members/. So I cannot set any defaults for the parent Members folder, from which all members' Home folders could inherit in return...

Of course, I could iterate through all Members with a script and set the folder_constraintypes for each Home folder. That would set things for all old members. However, that would have to be done again for each new member.

I find it very puzzling for users to let them have 8 and more content types to be addable within there Home folder, while they only need to use 2 or 3 actually. How can I change this?

Comment: The question is little bit difficult to follow (are there some mark-up problems). You mean you cannot set any settings in or the /Members/ folder?

Comment: you are right there were some formating problem, hope now it is clearer!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a content type for your members folder. And in the manage_afteradd method set all you want.

You we'll be able to configure Plone to use your content type as member folder, this will fix your problem for new users.

For all previously created members folders, as you said, you write a script that iterate over all members folders.

Answer (score 0):

The members-folder has the member_search_form-template set as default-view. This template doesn't show the link to the folder_constraintypes-template, but you can access the template by appending its name at the end of the member-folder's url.

'http://localhost:8080/yourSiteName/Members/folder_constraintypes'

Note: Don't exclude folders, otherwise the userfolders cannot be created automatically :)

Comment: I know about 'http://localhost:8080/yourSiteName/Members/folder_constraintypes' -- the problem is that there is no "Specify types manually" option available there (so no way to exclude anything, also no folders ;)